# Need ruby error message as instance variable

Tags: ruby, json, exception, sinatra

I have a custom error class like this:

```
class EntityCrudError < StandardError
    attr_reader :action
    attr_reader :modelName
    attr_reader :entity
    attr_reader :errors
    def initialize(action, model, entity = nil)
      @action = action
      @model = model
      @entity = entity
      @errors = entity.respond_to?(:errors) ? entity.errors : nil
    end
end
```

I use this in a Sinatra web application. When the error occurs I send an instance of this object in JSON format:

```
myError.to_json
```

this `to_json` method is the [ActiveSupport implementation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/JSON.html).

However, the message is not in the JSON object since it's not an instance variable. I need that message in my JSON object. I had two ideas to do this but both of them don't work...

1. Make the message an instance variable in `initialize`, but there it doesn't seem to exist yet.
2. **Merge** the message into the JSON object, but I don't know how to merge it.

Which of both is the best and how do I implement it?

Comment: what is the attribute that is missing called? myError.message?

Comment: @MatthewGraves Yes, but `.message` is a function that returns it. That's the way Errors work in Ruby.

Comment: Thank you for the ruby lesson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just thought of something that works:

```
class EntityCrudError < StandardError
  ..
  ..

  def to_json
    @message = self.message
    super
  end
end
```

So I just make an instance variable when I need to JSONify the class, and then let the `super` implementation do the rest.